# Javascript: Passing a special argument

Tags: javascript, arguments

I remember coming across the solution for this problem.. There is a special term for this type of argument if I am not wrong.. But I just can't remember exactly what it is. I try searching for it on the web but to no avail.. So here it comes:

**I want to pass an argument that consists of a function.** What should I do?

```
function meow(cat){
    var z = $("#nyan").position().cat;
    alert(z);
}

meow(left);
```

or

```
function meow(cat){
    var z = $("#nyan").cat();
    alert(z);
}

meow(height);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not quite a function; it looks more like you want a name of a property.

I'm just going to throw a few suggestions at you and see which one you like the most.

```
function meow(cat) {
    var z = $("#nyan").position()[cat];
    alert(z);
}

meow("left");
```

... or ...

```
function meow(cat) {
    var z = $("#nyan")[cat]();
    alert(z);
}

meow("height");
```

... or, really using a function:

```
function meow(getter) {
    var z = getter($("#nyan"));
    alert(z);
}

meow(function(nyan) { return nyan.position().left });
meow(function(nyan) { return nyan.position().top });
// etc.
```

**Edit**: the most important thing is that `a.b` is equivalent to `a["b"]`—note the quotes in the latter.

So if you want `a.x` if `width` is `true` *or* `a.y` if `width` is `false`, for example:

```
var result = a[width ? "x" : "y"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `call` to call the function that was passed as an argument:

```
function meow(cat) {
    var z = cat.call($("#nyan"));
    alert(z);
}

meow($.fn.height);
```

Comment: By way of explanation: `func.call`, where `func` is a function, takes as the first argument the value of `this` for the duration of `func`.

Answer (score 0):

The given solutions will work but they won't work if you want the function to accept both property/attribute and functions.

Try this:

```
function meow(cat){
  var z = typeof cat == 'function' ? $("#nyan").[z]() : $("#nyan")[z];
  alert(z);
}

meow(left);
```

Modify this to suite your needs.